# Depth peeling without occlusion query

Tags: algorithm, glsl, webgl

I want to implement the "depth peeling" in webgl but the problem is that there is no occlusion query so  I don't know how to check when the "peeling" of the scene is over.

Do you see an other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to limit the peeling to a certain amount of steps. This is sometimes even better than using occlusion queries because to many layers of transparent structure become close to impossible to discern from each other. It often helps to know what you are exactly rendering to get a good estimate of the amount of layers you need to peel.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented depth peeling in webgl. There are a few limiting factors that make it kinda hard to do as many peels as layers. Mainly a very limited amount of texture units and the fact you can only render to one target at a time, so you have to render color and depth seperately. With 7 textures used I can do 4 peels. That already takes 11 render passes per frame. To do more peels you would need to do a bit more sophisticated merging of intermediate results. I doubt you gain much from more peels.

Comment: if i understand correctly i don't have to peel all the layers to have a realistic result ?

Comment: right, as pmr said in his answer, too many layers of transparent structure become close to impossible to discern from each other

Comment: just a question : how do you collect the color of, for instance, the second layer of the scene ? It is "easy" to collect the depth of this layer but since there isn't the "gl_Color" command in glsl es i don't see how to do that. Thanks

Comment: don't understand the question, what do you mean by collect

Comment: I mean that to compute the final color you need the colors of all the fragments so how do you get the second layer color ?

Comment: Well the final step is to bind all the textures with your intermediate results, merge them in the fragment shader and render it on a quad that spans the area you want to render to, most likely your whole canvas.

Comment: but in your textures you have the color of all the layers right ? So how do you get those colors ?

Comment: I think that i have to compute the color in my shader using the position of the lights, the normal vector ...